# Why is my localized variable keep saying undefined?

Tags: wordpress

I am little new to wordpress. I have tried so many different attempts trying to make this work but can seem to  resolve the issue.

It keeps saying that ML_MOVIE_LISTING is undefined, when i try to localize it.

Below is my php code and javascript file.

Any help would really appreciated. Thanks!

```
function admin_scripts (){




    wp_enqueue_style("admin-style",plugins_url("style-admin.css",__FILE__));

wp_enqueue_style("jquery-ui","https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/external/jquery/jquery.js");
wp_enqueue_script("main_js",plugins_url("main.js",__FILE__),["jquery","jquery-ui-sortable"]);

    wp_localize_script("ml-script","ML_MOVIE_LISTING",[

    "token"=>wp_create_nonce("ml-token")

]);



}

add_action("admin_init","admin_scripts");
```

**JS CODE**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){



    var movie_sort_list = $(".movie-sort-list"),
        order_save_msg = $(".order-save-msg"),
        order_save_error = $(".order-save-err");



    console.log(ML_MOVIE_LISTING);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the reason why it wasn't working was because the name in the first parameter was different then the name of the first paramaeter in
wp_enqueue_script() They both have to be the same as shown below

```
wp_enqueue_script("main_js",plugins_url("main.js",__FILE__),["jquery","jquery-ui-sortable"]);

wp_localize_script("main_js","ML_MOVIE_LISTING",[

    "token"=>wp_create_nonce("ml-token")

]);
```